# C# : how to modify properties of dynamically created controls like panels etc

Tags: c#, .net

I need help with modifying the properties of a dynamically created controls.

First I created 2 panels on the form dynamically like this:

```
    public void create_panels()
    {
        Panel panel1 = new Panel();
        panel1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        panel1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        panel1.Size = new Size(320, 480);
        this.Controls.Add(panel1);

        Panel panel2 = new Panel();
        panel2.BackColor = Color.Red;
        panel2.Location = new Point(320, 0);
        panel2.Size = new Size(320, 480);
        this.Controls.Add(panel2);
    }
```

The problem I can't seam to find any clear information about how to modify them after they where (dynamically) created. One would thinks that simply doing something like this below would be easy and nice: (to change the panels color and position). However, this obviously doesn't work since the panel was created dynamically:

```
        panel1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        panel1.Location = new Point(320, 0);
```

Can someone please help post the simplest way to modify properties of dynamically made control (panel or textbox) changing the controls location or color after it has been created in a dynamic method?

Comment: I really can't see why your approach should *not* work. Can you provide a [mcve] please? What happens to your panels instead of having the desired background color and position?

Comment: do you have exactly 2 of them on the form...or is this more dynamic than that?

Comment: The answer lies is in the way you identify which panels you want to change the properties of.

Comment: Make `panel1` and `panel2` fields of your `Form` class instead of local variables if you want to access them later (outside `create_panels` method).

Comment: @René Vogt Can you please give me an example of how I would add the 2 panels to my Form Class. I was able to get my solution to work below with John Wu's Approach. However, if later I decide to create panels using a variable array I am curious how I would also be able to do do that later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still have a reference to the control, you can of course just set the properties directly, as in the following example. The trick is to save the reference as a form-scope variable (instead of as a local variable).

```
class SomeForm : Form
{
    protected Panel _panel1;

    public Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _panel1 = new Panel
        {
            BackColor = Color.Red,
            Location = new Point(0, 0),
            Size = new Size(320, 480)
        };
        this.Controls.Add(panel1);
    }

    public void Example()
    {
        _panel1.BackColor = Color.Blue; //Simple to change it if you have a reference already
    }
}
```

If you don't want to keep a reference, you can also grab one from the Controls collection, like this:

```
class SomeForm : Form
{
    public Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel panel1 = new Panel
        {
            Name = "SomeNameICanUse", //Important!
            BackColor = Color.Red,
            Location = new Point(0, 0),
            Size = new Size(320, 480)
        };

        this.Controls.Add(panel1);
    }

    public void Example()
    {
        var panel1 = this.Controls.Find("SomeNameICanUse") as Panel; //use the name to find it
        if (panel1 != null) panel1.BackColor = Color.Blue; 
    }
}
```

Comment: @ John Wu Thanks so much for the valuable help and your time. It looks like the part I was missing was the ("protected Panel _panel1;") part before my private void. After I added this, it allowed me to access the panel by name outside of the function. That was the missing piece! Without it... the IDE wouldn't even give me any indication that panel1 was an existing object that could be used. Now it acts just like a normal panel if i had drawing it in the designer.